Given $f$ convex, is there a meaningful family of curves $\alpha(t)$ such that $t\mapsto f(\alpha(t))$ is still convex?
If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex, then it is convex along at least these two types of curves:

Lines (obviously by definition);
Gradient flow trajectories. This is also easy to see, at least if everything is smooth enough, because the gradient flow satisfies
$$ \alpha'(t)=-\nabla f(\alpha(t)) $$
and if we take the second derivative of the composition $t\mapsto f(\alpha(t))$, we get:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}f(\alpha(t)) = \nabla f (\alpha(t))\cdot\alpha'(t) = -\|\nabla f (\alpha(t))\|^2 $$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(\alpha(t)) = 2 \nabla f(\alpha(t))^\top H_f(\alpha(t)) \nabla f(\alpha(t)) \ge 0 $$
since the hessian is positive semidefinite.

My question: is there a meaningful family of curves (which would include these two examples) such that the compositions $f \circ \alpha$ are always a (univariate) convex function?

You mean specifically the gradient of $f$, not of a general function. Also, you're missing a square in the first displayed equation.

Sure, the gradient of $f$. I do understand that, if a condition exists, it depends on the function. Thank you for catching the typo!

Also, $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} ( f \circ \gamma) (t) = \gamma'(t)^\top H_f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) + \nabla f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma''(t)$. The first term is non negative. The natural condition for the curve is to make the second term $\ge0$. Do you know if this has any interpretation? (for example analogous to "gradient flow always takes the direction of steepest descent")
